Taipy Menu open by default
I'm building a webapp with taipy and i'm using mainly the taipy gui builder.
I use the "menu" element to navigate between different pages and this is working well. However, taipy shows the menu by default folded and you have to click on it to unfold it and see all the options fully.
Does anybody have any idea how to set the menu by default on unfolded?
I will add a simplified example:
from taipy.gui import Gui

options = [("a", "Option A"), ("b", "Option B"), ("c", "Option C"), ("d", "Option D")]


with tgb.Page() as page:
   tgb.menu(label = "options",
            lov = options)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gui(page).run(title="Menu - Selected")

This is how it currently opens when you start the app
And this is how i want it to open when the app is started
The menu element doesn't seem to have any standard properties for this. I also tried to look for the taipy-menu css class, but couldn't find it (i have taipy 4.0.0 installed).

This is not yet possible in <=4.0.1. I have created a Github issue so that it will be possible in the future. You can provide your feedback there too.
